# Dxf file generated using ezdxf doesn't render text in 3d model when viewed in Autodesk Viewer

Tags: python, 3d, autodesk-viewer, dxf, ezdxf

I have written code that created dxf file with 2 cylinders stacked on top of each other, most of the part is working fine except when I add text into the 3d model it doesn't show in the Autodesk Viewer, any idea why or any possible fix? Below is my code

```
import ezdxf
from ezdxf.render import forms
from ezdxf.gfxattribs import GfxAttribs
from ezdxf import colors
from ezdxf.math import UCS, Vec3
from ezdxf.enums import TextEntityAlignment

# create the DXF document and model space
doc = ezdxf.new()
doc.styles.new('TXT', dxfattribs={'font': 'romans.shx'})
msp = doc.modelspace()

# create the first cylinder with a height of 10
cylinder_1 = forms.cylinder(radius=1.0, count=8).scale(1, 1, 5)
green = GfxAttribs(color=colors.GREEN)

# create the second cylinder with a height of 5
cylinder_2 = forms.cylinder(radius=1.0, count=8).scale(1, 1, 2)
blue = GfxAttribs(color=colors.BLUE)

# render the first cylinder as a MESH entity
cylinder_1.render_polyface(msp, dxfattribs=green)

# add text to first cylinder
ucs_1 = UCS(origin=(0, 0, 10), ux=(1, 0, 0), uz=(0, 1, 0))
text_1 = msp.add_text("Cylinder 1", dxfattribs={
    'rotation': ucs_1.to_ocs(Vec3(45, 0, 0)).angle_deg,
    'extrusion': ucs_1.uz,
    'color': 1,
    'style': 'TXT',
}).set_placement(ucs_1.to_ocs((0, 0, 0)), align=TextEntityAlignment.CENTER)

# translate the second cylinder to stack at bottom of first cylinder
cylinder_2.translate(0, 0, -2)

# render the second cylinder as a MESH entity
cylinder_2.render_polyface(msp, dxfattribs=blue)


doc.saveas("test.dxf")
```

I am only getting this view below in Autodesk Viewer, can't see any text
[image]

Hope to get some help on this. thank you all

Comment: I just tried with the .dxf generated by the code you shared and got the same result (no text). Even when I tried in AutoCAD I could not see the text. Is there any Viewer showing the text for this file?

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to see it through AutoCAD. I'm sharing it with engineering team to investigate. I'll share updates here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to let `ezdxf` do the transformation than setting the OCS and rotation "by hand":

```
# add text to first cylinder
ucs_1 = UCS(origin=(0, 0, 10), ux=(1, 0, 0), uz=(0, 1, 0))
text_1 = msp.add_text("Cylinder 1", dxfattribs={
    'color': 1,
    'style': 'TXT',
}).set_placement((0, 0, 0), align=TextEntityAlignment.CENTER)
# the text is placed in the xy-plane of the UCS
# transform the text from UCS to WCS (OCS is managed automatically)
text_1.transform(ucs_1.matrix)
```

and you get this:

[image]

but I'm pretty sure that's what you wanted:

[image]

Therefore select the UCS as follows: text x-axis in WCS-x and text y-axis in WCS-z:

```
ucs_1 = UCS(origin=(0, 0, 10), ux=(1, 0, 0), uy=(0, 0, 1))
```